# Error package com.sun.javafx.application is not visible

Tags: java, javafx, splash-screen, preloader

So when i want to add preloader to my app and add line with LauncherImpl, I have a problem with launch my app beacuse i got error like:

```
java: package com.sun.javafx.application is not visible
  (package com.sun.javafx.application is declared in module javafx.graphics, which does not export it to module pl.mr.scanner)
```

This problem is only when I try to add preloader.

Comment: a) don't use internal classes b) if you insist: add-opens for internal packages to the runtime arguments

Comment: `com.sun.*` packages are not part of the public API.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59957047/why-launcherimpl-launchapplication-javafx-launcher-in-the-main-class-are-lau